# Is it safe to delete the /Developer folder on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

My computer originally had Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) installed on it but has since been upgraded to OS X 10.7 (Lion). I noticed that the `/Developer` folder is still on the hard drive even though none of its files *appear* to have been modified for nearly two years. Is it safe to delete `/Developer` or is there some reason to keep it around?

[Chris Rea's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83868/13101) includes a link to [a guide to uninstall Xcode](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/), which seems to suggest that the contents of `/Developer` are only used by versions of Xcode prior to 4.3. I have already installed Xcode 4.6 on my machine, so I should be able to remove `/Developer` and everything under it. That being said, the following statement in the aforementioned guide puzzled me a bit.

> ```
> sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=xcodedir
> ```
>
> This command is basically a shortcut to the previously mentioned “/Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder” script. If you want to ditch the /Developer directory, run this command rather than manually deleting it through the Finder.

Why should I run this script instead of simply deleting `/Developer` through the Finder?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255959) is related, but I don't want to fully remove Xcode 4. I just want to remove all traces of Xcode that are not needed by the latest version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it should be safe to remove `/Developer` if you have already installed version 4.3 or later of Xcode. [The Xcode section of the Apple Developer Support Center](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) actually tells you to do this (emphasis mine).

> ### I've installed the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store, but a previous version of Xcode (4.2.1 or earlier) keeps launching. What should I do?
>
> ---
>
> To run the latest version of Xcode, make sure you are launching Xcode.app from the Applications folder. Xcode 4.3 and later is packaged on the Mac App Store as a single application and installs in your Applications folder as Xcode.app.
>
> **Previous versions of Xcode placed the tools and frameworks in the Developer folder. You can delete the older version of Xcode by dragging the Developer folder to the trash.**

Furthermore, [as pointed out by bispymusic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83874/13101), [`/Developer` no longer exists with Xcode 4.3](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html). Specifically (emphasis mine):

> **The simplification afforded by repackaging Xcode 4.3 as a single app bundle eliminates the need for the `/Developer` directory containing prior versions of Xcode.** As a result, **the Install Xcode application and the `uninstall-devtools` command line script are also no longer needed.**
>
> **Note:** The first time you run Xcode 4.3, you are prompted with a dialog to delete the Install Xcode application from the Applications directory if one is resident, and to remove any older installation of Xcode (Figure 4). These actions are optional, **Xcode 4.3 can co-exist with older installations of Xcode on the same Mac.** Some operations may require an administrator password to enable them if you switch from one version of Xcode to another.
>
> **Figure 4**  Option to remove older versions of Xcode
>
> [image: Xcode screenshot]
>
> If you choose not to delete these items on the first launch of Xcode 4.3, **you can remove the `/Developer` folder and the Install Xcode application by dragging them to the Trash at any time.**

Answer (score 1):

Did you already upgrade your Xcode to a newer version, one stored under `/Applications`? If you upgraded to a newer Xcode stored in the new location and also installed the updated Command Line Tools from within Xcode, then what you have under the root `/Developer` folder is likely all stale and you can probably safely delete `/Developer`.  **To be safe,** archive the folder elsewhere for the time being, then nuke it later when you are confident you don't need it.

If you did *not* install the more recent Xcode, I'm guessing the contents under `/Developer` may still be "in effect."  Have a look at [this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/) to uninstall the developer tools in that case.  Make sure your environment variables don't refer to any paths within the folder.

Comment: Yes, I've already installed the latest version of Xcode, but it doesn't look like I've installed the Command Line Tools yet. I'll do that now. Are there some path variables that I can check to ensure that the appropriate command-line tools are being referenced? (For what it's worth, `xcode-select -print-path` is returning `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xcode 4.3 or later, it should be safe to remove this file. Apple elaborates on it here:

[What's New in Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html)